# Swapping dynamically between text and data-text with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying this code to switch dynamically my text in an announcement bar.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  let text1 = document.querySelector("text1");
  function changeText( ) {
    if (text1.getAttribute("data-text2") == text1.innerHTML) {
      text1.innerHTML = text1.getAttribute("data-text1");
    } else {
      text1.setAttribute("data-text1", text1.innerHTML);
      text1.innerHTML = text1.getAttribute("data-text2");
    }
    window.setTimeout(function() { 
      changeText() }, 3000);
    } 
  })
```

```html
<span class="text1" data-text2="Livraison gratuite partout au Canada.">Le Tero et Tero Plus en vente maintenant.</span>
```

Anybody can tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Your code could be simplified a lot, using _dataset_ and _ternary operator_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you didn't select your element correctly. `let text1 = document.querySelector(".text1");` you should use `.text` instead of `text`.

Second, you have some syntax error in your code, the curly bracket is not well placed.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  let text1 = document.querySelector(".text1");
  function changeText() {
    if (text1.getAttribute("data-text2") == text1.innerHTML) {
      text1.innerHTML = text1.getAttribute("data-text1");
    } else {
      text1.setAttribute("data-text1", text1.innerHTML);
      text1.innerHTML = text1.getAttribute("data-text2");
    }
  }

  window.setTimeout(function () {
    changeText();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<span class="text1" data-text2="Livraison gratuite partout au Canada.">Le Tero et Tero Plus en vente maintenant.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Often times, especially with `innerHTML`  you need to `trim()` your strings for comparisons, like:

```
text1.getAttribute("data-text2") == text1.innerHTML.trim()
```

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  let text1 = document.querySelector("text1");
  function changeText( ) {
    if (text1.getAttribute("data-text2") == text1.innerHTML.trim()) {
      text1.innerHTML = text1.getAttribute("data-text1");
    } else {
      text1.setAttribute("data-text1", text1.innerHTML.trim());
      text1.innerHTML = text1.getAttribute("data-text2");
    }
    window.setTimeout(function() { 
      changeText() }, 3000);
    } 
  })
```

```html
<span class="text1" data-text2="Livraison gratuite partout au Canada.">Le Tero et Tero Plus en vente maintenant.</span>
```